# Calling Rcpp with matrix input

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp

I have a function in c++ (basically, plain C) with the following signature

```
#define LONMAX 1440
int readRT2B (int lmax,char buf[][LONMAX*2],float out[][LONMAX]);
```

it basically receives a fixed size [LATMAX,LONMAX] matrix of bytes , massages it a bit and gets back a matrix of floats

The data is read from the binary gzip'ed file. So, on R side I read the file, prepare the integer matrix rawData (really bytes, 0:255)

```
class(rawData) 
[1]  "matrix"
dim(rawData) 
[1]  480 2880
```

and need to pass it to the cpp function and get back matrix of floats

So I created Rcpp file,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

#define _BIG_ENDIAN 1
#define LONMAX 1440
using namespace Rcpp;

int status = readXRT2B(LATMAX60, raw_buffer, out60);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List read3B42RT(NumericMatrix raw_buffer){
  List list_out;
  NumericMatrix out60(LATMAX60,LONMAX);

  //actual worker
  int status = readXRT2B(LATMAX60, raw_buffer, out60);

  list_out["P"]=out60;

  return (Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("P")=out60));
}

//worker
int status = readXRT2B(LATMAX60, raw_buffer, out60){
    // implementation details, not important
    return 0;
}
```

> error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::NumericVector {aka Rcpp::Vector<14,
>   Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}' to 'char (*)[2880]' for argument '2' to 'int
>   readRT2B(int, char (*)[2880], float (*)[1440])'

Comment: I think your interfaces are a bit, well, unusual and unsuitable.  There is a "raw" type in R (and a corresponding `SEXP`). Maybe that would help?  I'd work out the problem in C first, and then worry about the interface.

Comment: Or try the reverse and use _existing_ data types: a matrix of integers, and a matrix of doubles.

Comment: You are probably right, I am new to the whole Rcpp business, and frankly haven't done much in cpp for the last decade or so, so I concede, the interfaces probably are unusual, probably even not a bit, but a lot :) 
On the topic I actually do get the raw integers first that I convert to matrix before passing it to Rcpp. I thought that if C interface expects a matrix I'll convert it to matrix to make things easier. I actually have no problem with either way, as long as it makes sense and works ;)
It does work in C - it's suggested by the data provider, and it actually works in Visual Studio.